# ListBox scrollbars not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, margin, scrollbars

OK this is a problem about which I've found tons of pages.
They say to put

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"    
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
```

but that doesn't work.
In another post they say to put a defined height/width and that works!!
The only problem is that I can't put a predefined height/widht because the listbox has to adapt to its parent through margin=0.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbxOptionsTab3" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" FontSize="12" Width="190"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Bold" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" Margin="0">
```

So how can I make scrollbars to appear?

Thank you in advance.
Patrick

---ADD---
The complete xaml is too complex to be put here.
But part of is:

```
<Border x:Name="Border2Tab3" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" Background="{x:Null}"  MinWidth="100" BorderThickness="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,10,10"  >
   <Border.Effect>
       <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="4" Direction="330" Color="Black" Opacity="0.5" BlurRadius="4"/>
   </Border.Effect>
   <Grid Name="gdTab3" Margin="0" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
   <!-- LB1 GENERAL -->
   <ListBox x:Name="lb1Tab3" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="1500" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  FontSize="{StaticResource BUTTON_FONTSIZE}" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >

        ...All elements in the listBox

   </ListBox> 

   ...other listBoxes
```

Comment: The listbox needs to know it's size to show the scrollbars, if you don't define a size the bars will not appear, maybe you can set the with and height after loading the control and retrieving it at runtime?

Comment: I could yes but the window can change size and I have to adapt to it

Comment: Well, then hook to the resize event and change the listbox size accordingly to the left space.

Comment: Put a fix height in `ListBox`. If values exceed that height, ScrollBar will be visible.

Comment: Can you post your full code of xaml that include parent of `ListBox`

Comment: Please everyone see my ADD. Thanks